# How to merge multiple similar words into one python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of words

```
names = ['ASO', 'TSLA', 'GME']
```

and I have a dataframe

```
                                dt  ...                                               text
0        2021-03-19 14:59:49+00:00  ...  I only need ASO:"@ASO[]ASO^%$ASO to hit 20 eod to make up for a...
1        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...                                 Oh this isn’t good
2        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...  lads why is my account covered in more red ink..
```

In case words from the list match with each row I need to create a function.
If there are 3 or more similar words from the list like in row one, I want to keep only one version of this word, keep in mind signs. I don't care if there will be signs or not but it is important to keep one version of the word
output that I want

```
                                dt  ...                                               text
0        2021-03-19 14:59:49+00:00  ...  I only need ASO to hit 20 eod to make up for a...
1        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...                                 Oh this isn’t good
2        2021-03-19 14:59:51+00:00  ...  lads why is my account covered in more
```

Here is what I tried

```
price = pd.read_csv('top_20_tickers.csv')
names = list(price.columns)
names.pop(0)
discussion = pd.read_csv('wsb_comments.csv', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
discussion = discussion.drop_duplicates('text')
discussion = discussion[discussion['text'].notnull()]


def check_words(sentence, names):
    words = sentence.split()
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        if word in names:
            count += 1
    return count > 3


discussion['Contains_4+_words'] = discussion.apply(lambda r: check_words(r.text, names), axis=1)
discussion = discussion[discussion['Contains_4+_words'] == False]
```

but it removes the whole row but instead i need to merge certain words
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your text is confusing. Either put a proper punctuation in there of maybe try to put it as a list of items.

Comment: please see the comment

Comment: Why is there two dataframes? What is the second one about?

Comment: the second one is the output that I want to get look at row 1 and then there is fixed version of row 1

Answer (score 0):

Would this work ?

```py
words = ['ASO', 'TSLA']
def merge_words(words, phrase):
    for word in words:
        sections = phrase.split(word)
        if len(sections)>= 3:
            res = sections[0]  + word + sections[-1]
            print(res)
            return res
        else:
            return phrase
f = lambda x: (merge_words(words, x['text']))

discussion['text'] = discussion.apply(f, axis=1)
```

*PS: it is easier to iterate and give an answer if you provide Dataframe sample directly in code*

Comment: it tells me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
on line sections = phrase.split(word)

Comment: in the column 'text' you sometimes have lists, not strings ?

Comment: there is only text in this column

Comment: names is the list everything else is a string

Comment: Yeah I just copied your code and that was the error that I got